# How to use your USB External drive as primary drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, usb, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive

I would like to use my main Internal drive to install software's but use my external USB drive to saves my files. Sound simple but I want it to be done automatically, like exchanging My Documents, Downloads ect to my External Drive, so when I Open My Documents its located in my External Drive. is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into disk-management and give the USB drive a specific letter name as a drive path.  Do this by going `Windows+R` then type `diskmgmt.msc`.  Right click on the USB drive and select a drive letter for it.

Next go to start button and click on your user name.  Right click on the `My Documents` folder and select `Properties`.  Now go to `Location` and define the USB drive as the destination for your Documents.

Warning: If you ever format the USB drive you will need to re-setup the drive letter name in `diskmgmt.msc`.

EDIT:  Since you are using WINDOWS 10 you can get to `diskmgmt.msc` by right clicking the start button.

Answer (score 1):

Possible. Whether it is a good idea or not - it is for you to find out (as accessing external drive is often slower than having things on an internal HDD - AND also with the reason explained by Matthew Rummins answer).

1. Open File Explorer
2. On the left hand side - find the "Documents" - Right click and choose "Properties"
3. Click on "Location" tab, and simply click on "Move" and choose your USB drive and the particular folder you wanted the "Documents" folder to be redirected to.

Repeat the above for other default folders (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, and Videos)